# A CNAME with a wildcard embedded

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, domain-name, wildcard

I'm trying to set up a CNAME DNS entry:

```
start.*.example.com
```

That matches the following domain names:

```
start.a.b.c.example.com
start.a.example.com
```

Is this possible? My current tests are failing with networksolutions.com.

It was previously working as an A record wildcard (*.exmaple.com) - but I would like it to work as a CNAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start.*.example.com`

DNS wildcards do not work like this, so you can not do that (as a wildcard) and hence "embedded wildcard" is not a thing in DNS world.

It is not a problem of the record type (`CNAME` vs `A` vs anything else) or the DNS provider used, it is the fact that a wildcard HAS TO be a first label of `*` and then other labels.

So `*.example.com` is a wildcard (and hence will trigger specific behavior during DNS exchanges, matching multiple names) but `start.*.example.com` is not a wildcard: you can certainly create a `CNAME` record with this name, however it will match only itself, literally, including with the asterisk, and absolutely nothing else (no matching of any other name)

See RFC 1034:

> 4.3.3. Wildcards
>
> In the previous algorithm, special treatment was given to RRs with owner
> names starting with the label "*".  Such RRs are called wildcards.

and later:

> The contents of the wildcard RRs follows the usual rules and formats for
> RRs.  The wildcards in the zone have an owner name that controls the
> query names they will match.  The owner name of the wildcard RRs is of
> the form "*.", where  is any domain name.

If you need to match a single thing, you can create the wildcard of `*.example.com` and both `start.a.example.com` and `start.a.b.c.example.com` will match the wildcard record, but as would any other name where `start` and/or `a` and/or `b` and/or `c` are replaced by something else.

The Wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record has exactly the same content as above:

> Say there is a DNS zone with the following resource records:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> *.example.               3600     TXT   "this is a wildcard"
> *.example.               3600     MX    10 host1.example.
> sub.*.example.           3600     TXT   "this is not a wildcard"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The following responses would be synthesized from one of the wildcards in the zone:
>
> [...]
>
> foo.bar.example.  TXT     The answer will be "foo.bar.example. IN TXT ..." because bar.example. does not exist, but the wildcard does.
>
> [...]
>
> The following responses would not be synthesized from any of the wildcards in the zone:
>
> [...]
>
> sub.*.example.   MX  No wild card will match because sub.*.example. exists. The domain sub.*.example. will never act as a wild card, even though it has an asterisk in it.